# Unix for loop multiple variables

Tags: bash, awk, sql

I have a requirement of extracting the 2nd, 3rd and 4th field  from a file `aaa.log` and producing output as

```
- sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"COL3:COL4/COL2\"
```

Input:

```
$ cat aaa.log
aaa:fDb:a0081:1800:f1:dsds
aaa:iDb:a0081:1801:i1:dsds
aaa:pDb:a0081:1802:p1:dsds
```

Expected Output:

```
sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"a0081:1800/fDb\"    
sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"a0081:1801/iDb\"
sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"a0081:1802/pDb\"
```

I extracted  COL2 into a file:

```
$ cat aaa.log | cut -d":" -f2 > aaa_i.log
$ cat aaa_i.log
fDb
iDb
pDb
```

and extracted COL3 and COL4:

```
$ cat aaa.log | awk -F: '{print  $3  ":" $4}' > aaa_h_p.log
$ cat aaa_h_p.log
a0081:1800
a0081:1801
a0081:1802
```

I tried using the below code.

```sh
  set -f
 IFS='
> '
 set -- $( cat aaa_i.log)
for i in `cat aaa_h_p.log`
do
 printf "%s %s\n" "sqlplus -sl sys/hSys10Nov@\""${i}"/"$1"\""
 done
```

Current Ouput:

```
sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"a0081:1800/fDb\"
sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"a0081:1801/fDb\"
sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"a0081:1802/fDb\"
```

I am getting only fDb in COL2 in the o/p, whereas I want all the values there. Please help me correct the code. Even changes using AWK are welcome.

Comment: Bash only supports one variable in a `for` loop; zsh supports at least two, if not more.  (I've never needed to use more than two.)

Comment: Also backticks (e.g. `\``) are discouraged: use `$(...)` instead.  see: [Bash Hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) for more information.

Comment: Any other loop that could help the purpose or AWK utility ?

Comment: awk is more than powerful enough to do what I think you're trying to do, and I'm pretty sure it supports multiple variables in its loops.  Try something like `echo aaa:fDb:a0081:1800:f1:dsds | awk -F ':' '{printf("%s\n", "sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"$3:$4/$2\""); }'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are nice for this kind of thing (especially if you're not sure how many fields there are):

```
while IFS=: read -a var; do 
  printf 'sqlplus -s1 dbsnmp/Or8cle@\\"%s:%s/%s\\"\n' "${var[2]}" "${var[3]}" "${var[1]}"
done < aaa.log
sqlplus -s1 dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"a0081:1800/fDb\"
sqlplus -s1 dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"a0081:1801/iDb\"
sqlplus -s1 dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"a0081:1802/pDb\"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
while IFS=: read a b c d e f;do 
    echo sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"$c:$d/$b\" 
done < aaa.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below awk solution -

```
vipin@kali:~$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print v1$3,$4v2$2v3}' v1='sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\\"' v2='/' v3='\\"' OFS=":" kk.txt
sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"a0081:1800/fDb\"
sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"a0081:1801/iDb\"
sqlplus -sl dbsnmp/Or8cle@\"a0081:1802/pDb\"
```

FS,OFS = field seperators.
v1,v2,v3 = variables to print sentences as per our requirement.